# How to maintain the distance between two nodes in a graph? C++

Tags: c++

I am working on a graph problem in which I have to implement graph for which I am given two starting nodes and the two target nodes respectively. I also have to maintain the distance between the nodes through the entire path. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the a-star algorithm to explore the graph as you move, to maintain the distance between the nodes. [A-star on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star) this should serve your purpose.

Comment: By the way, do you know where to find the c++ implementation of this algorithm?